# Reducing the memory footprint of a C# application

Tags: c#, memory-management

I am developing a C# application which needs to process approximately 4,000,000 english sentences. All these sentences are being stored in a tree. Where each node in the tree is a class which has these fields:

```
class TreeNode
{
    protected string word;
    protected Dictionary<string, TreeNode> children;
}
```

My problem is that the application is using up all the RAM (I have 2 GB RAM) when it reaches the 2,000,000th sentence. So it only manages to process half the sentences and then it slows down drastically.

What can I do to try and reduce the memory footprint of the application?

EDIT: Let me explain a bit more my application. So I have approximately 300,000 english sentences, and from each sentence I am generating further sub sentences like this:

Example: 
Sentence: Football is a very popular sport
Sub Sentences I need:

1. Football is a very popular sport
2. is a very popular sport
3. a very popular sport
4. very popular sport
5. popular sport
6. sport

Each sentence is stored in a tree word by word. So considering the example above, i have a TreeNode Class with the word field = "Football", and the children list has the TreeNode for the word "is". The child of the "is" node is the "a" node. The child for the "a" node is the "very" node. I need to store the sentences word by word since i need to be able to search for all the sentences starting with Example: "Football is".

So basically for each word in a sentence i am creating a new (sub-sentence). And this is the reason I ultimately end up with 4,000,000 different sentences. Storing the data in a database is not an option, since the app needs to work on the whole structure at once. And it will further slow down the process if i had to stay writing all the data to a database.

Thanks

Comment: To add to Marc's comment, why not store in a database, and let it manage memory paging? NOTE" apologies Marc I seem to have edited your comment rather than adding a  new one. Can I revert?

Comment: Do you really need all the sentences in memory at once?

Comment: Why are you storing them as a tree? What is the purpose of your app?

Comment: @Mitch - I think you ate my comment ;-p But basically I said: do you really need all the data in-memory? I'm thinking that there is possibly a streaming way of doing this...

Comment: @marc: sorry, I did. I couldn't see a way of reverting?

Comment: Yes I need the whole structure in memory. But as you can see from the example i gave, the tree will contain a lot of duplicate words, so using the StringCache described in the next post will help a lot I think, need to try it out.

Comment: Does the `children` dictionary only contain a single item ("is" in your example)? Then why do you need a dictionary?

Comment: No the children dictionary will contain all the words which come after the word football in the corpus.

Comment: @Spi1988 - thanks for taking the time to provide feedback about how this helped. That is **really** useful for the site, thinking about people who might visit this question in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is it you are using as the key? Where are you getting the data from? If these are **words** (not full setences), I'm wondering if you have a lot of *duplicated* keys (different `string` instances with the same fundamental value), in which case you might benefit from implementing a local interner to re-use the values (and let the transient copies get garbage collected).

```
public sealed class StringCache {
    private readonly Dictionary<string,string> values
        = new Dictionary<string,string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
    public string this[string value] {
        get {
            string cached;
            if (!values.TryGetValue(value, out cached)) {
                values.Add(value, value);
                cached = value;
            }
            return cached;
        }
    }
}
```

Instantiate this when building the tree, and use (when you think a value is likely to be duplicated):

```
StringCache cache = new StringCache(); // re-use this instance while building
                                       // your tree
...
string s = ... // whatever (from reading your input)
s = cache[s];
```

Comment: No question about it, this will reduce the memory requirements. There are far fewer than 4 million words - it's closer to 100k. Interning them will make a huge difference.

Comment: @Marc: any reason you would not use string.Intern()?

Comment: @Marc: I think I just discovered why!: memory might not be released until the CLR terminates...

Comment: @Mitch - indeed; the intent here was to allow the data to be shared for a controlled time / batch, not for the entire process.

Comment: @Cameron - well, I *guess* you could categorise a reference as a flyweight, but ultimately it is object re-use.

Comment: I implemented your solution, and the memory usage improved a lot. Before using your approach the system was filling up all my 2GB RAM when it reaches 1/3 of the whole process. Now it only uses up approx. 200MB of RAM for the whole process. The gain was enormous, because I have a lot of duplicate strings. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 4):

The Dictionary type itself can consume a lot of memory. Have you considered using a `List<KeyValuePair<string, TreeNode>>` instead? The generic `List` uses a lot less memory per instance than a generic `Dictionary`.

Of course, the limitation of using a List instead of a Dictionary is that you don't get automatic indexing by strings. This would be a clear trade off between time and space. If the lists are short, it might even be faster than the dictionary (a linear search of ~10 keys is often going to be faster than a hashtable search). Even if at least *most* of the lists are short, it could still be a large improvement (e.g. if 95% of the lists have 10 or fewer items, and the other 5% have a max of maybe 100 items).

You could even use `Collection<KeyValuePair<string, TreeNode>>`, which uses even less memory than `List<T>`.

Comment: So ... there is a HybridDictionary for that purpose. It starts out a a list and then turns into a dict.

Comment: Yes, there is HybridDictionary, but even it has some additional costs associated with it. HybridDictionary starts out using about 32 bytes of memory, Dictionary<K,V> about 44, List<T> about 16, and Collection<T> about 8. (This is excluding CLR overhead and assumes 32bit.)

Comment: I'll try out the HybridDictionary first, since if possible, i would like to keep the string indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Could you map each word to an int? That way you have one map of int to string that contains unique English words and a tree structure that contains sentences like so:

```
class TreeNode
{
    protected int word;
    protected Dictionary<int, TreeNode> children;
}

Dictionary<string, int> _AllWords;
```

Now the `_AllWords` collection is not optimal for looking up words based on a key as is. What you probably want here is something like a multi-key list where you can do fast lookup based on both key and value. [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/multikey-dictionary.aspx) has an article about that.

Comment: Note that on x86, this is actually the same as the "interner" suggestion I give, but without the requirement to do an extra lookup between the int key and a string value. Instead, each int **is** the reference itself.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is for performance and you feel as though you need all words in memory then I'd suggest you use a string array to contain all words. Then store all indexes into a sorted binary tree.

Answer (score 2):

Some points to think about.

1. When you initialize your Dictionary<,>, pass in the max number of items you need. This will make it allocate enough buckets at the startup. Default is to initialize with 0 buckets, which evaluates to 3(prime). Once you add more items, the dictionary must reinitialize and copy all items to a new larger storage. If you program never idles, then the GC will not collect the old Dictionaries.
2. You could save space by encoding your strings. Strings will use two bytes per character in memory. With some helper functions you could have your class like this:

```
    class TreeNode
    {
        protected byte[] word;
        protected Dictionary<byte[], TreeNode> children;

        public string Word
        {
            get { return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(word); }
            set { word = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value); }
        }

        public TreeNode GetChildByKey( string key )
        {
            TreeNode node;
            if(children.TryGetValue( Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key), out node  ))
            {
                return node;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[Edit]
And I forgot that you also need a new comparer for the byte[] key.

```
var children = new Dictonary<string,TreeNode>(new ByteArrayComparer);

public class ByteArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
{
    public bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(byte[] a)
    {
        return a[0] | (int)a[1] << 8 | (int)a[2] << 16 | (int)a[3] << 24;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness - encoding may have a place here since the question relates to "English sentences", but for some cultures this could actually double the memory used by the strings.

Comment: That's a nice observation which I actually didn't consider. I'm so used to work in the western character set. Before doing encoding, test and see if it helps. Using a variable byte structure might also help, specially if the strings are longer. But before going the compression way, you should reconsider the whole problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

It might be overkill for your situation but you could store your nodes in files on disk and use a [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) implementation to maximize IO performance.  This is what most databases use internally because there is simply too much data to store in memory.

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the memory footprint you should look for [Sequential Data Cache](http://sequentialdatacache.codeplex.com/).

It makes possible to reduce the memory footprint by the collection you use. (The collection item must be marked with [Serializable])

You can even make the collection permanent by passing deleteOnClose:false parameter

Sample

```
using (var c = SequentialDataCache<TreeNode>.Initialize(deleteOnClose: false))
        {
            //add items to collection
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                var treeNode = new TreeNode()
                                   {
                                       Word = string.Format("Word{0}", i),
                                       Children = new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>()
                                   };
                for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                {
                    var child = new TreeNode() { Word = string.Format("Word{0}", j) };
                    treeNode.Children.Add(string.Format("key{0}{1}", i, j), child);
                }
                c.Add(treeNode);
            }

            //assert query
            Assert.AreEqual("Word0", c[0].Word);
            Assert.AreEqual("Word1", c[0].Children["key01"].Word);
            Assert.AreEqual("Word100", c[100].Word);
        }
```

and the TreeNode...

```
    [Serializable]
    class TreeNode
    {
        private string word;
        private Dictionary<string, TreeNode> children;

        public string Word
        {
            get { return word; }
            set { word = value; }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, TreeNode> Children
        {
            get { return children; }
            set { children = value; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can **significantly** reduce memory usage is by not keeping the sentences in memory.

What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you building a tree? If you are counting something, count and discard the strings as your read them in. If you are building a graph (ie. to analysis relationships between sentence and/or words), try enumerating the sentences and words to they can be unique/key by that id. Use that id in memory instead.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm happy to report that there *were* ways of significantly reducing memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Great question, and some great answers.  I learned a lot.  The StringCache idea deserves some research.

I want to respond to the "I can't use a database because I need it all in memory" point.  In many cases, a database is actually the best solution.

Consider that a robust SQL database engine (I'm a MSSQL guy):

- Can hold much more data -- the size of your disk instead of the size of memory or swap space. (A SQL database can also leverage memory and disk on a separate machine, thereby increasing the available footprint with a trade-off of network latency.)
- Indexes the data for fast retrieval
- Dynamically caches the data used most often and frees less-used data when memory pressure dictates.
- Uses storage, retrieval, and caching algorithms developed by a large team over many years and tuned to adapt dynamically to a wide range of situations.

The dynamic caching could be a huge benefit for this solution set.  Assuming your corpus consists only of "normal" sentences, the word distribution will not be uniform.  The most frequent words will be accessed several orders of magnitude more often than the least frequent.  It's also likely the frequent words will be added to the dictionary very early, and therefore will be stored close together in the database.  A good SQL engine will cache the most frequently used blocks in memory, which naturally favors the kind of searches you describe.

A hybrid solution might look like this:

- A table with appropriate indexes

  ```
  create table myWords (wordKey int identity, word varchar(50))
  create unique index iword 
    on myWords(word)  -- used for adds and retrieval
  create unique index iwordKey 
    on myWords(wordKey) -- used for mapping keys back to words
  ```
- A stored procedure for adding/finding words.  Stored procedures conveniently return an int.

  ```
  create procedure addWord (@word varchar(50))
  as
  begin
    declare @wordKey int, @rows int
    insert myWords (word)
      select @word
      where not exists (select 1 from myWords where word = @word)
    select @wordKey = @@identity, @rows = @@rowcount
    if @rows = 0
    begin
      select @wordKey = wordKey
        from myWords
        where word = @word
    end
    return @wordKey
  end
  ```
- The application adds the words to the database, builds the tree in memory using only the wordKey values.
- Searching for a matching sentence would start with a query to get the wordKey values for the words in question, then analyze the tree, gather the wordKeys needed to construct the complete sentences, and finally retrieve those words using a second query.

You could trade a little speed building the database to further optimize the benefit from caching the most frequent words.

1. Add a field to the table (`usageCount int`).  Inserts set it to 1, updates increment.
2. With only the index on word, populate the dictionary table from your corpus
3. Add a clustered index on usageCount (desc), which will reorganize to bring the most frequent words close together.  (Maybe drop it again -- the good work is complete.)
4. Build your tree.

Even if your corpus grows in the future, the word frequencies are unlikely to change enough to affect efficiency.